# Extracting time and convert to column then group by date

Tags: sql, sql-server

this is my first post. I wanted to ask some help from everyone as i have tried to find a solution to my problem.

I currently have this data

```
Date                    Status   
----------------------- -------------
2013-01-02 08:49:31.000 A
2013-01-02 18:03:29.000 B
2013-01-03 08:54:59.000 A
2013-01-03 18:04:43.000 B
2013-01-04 08:53:26.000 A
2013-01-04 18:08:43.000 B
```

I wanted to have an output like this

```
Date                     A              B   
----------------------- ------------    ------------
2013-01-02 00:00:00.000 08:49:31.000    18:03:29.000
2013-01-03 00:00:00.000 08:54:59.000    18:04:43.000
2013-01-04 00:00:00.000 08:53:26.000    18:08:43.000
```

What my current output is this

```
Date                    A               B   
----------------------  ------------    ------------------
2013-01-02 00:00:00.000 08:49:31.000    NULL
2013-01-02 00:00:00.000 NULL            18:03:29.000
2013-01-03 00:00:00.000 08:54:59.000    NULL
2013-01-03 00:00:00.000 NULL            18:04:43.000
2013-01-04 00:00:00.000 08:53:26.000    NULL
2013-01-04 00:00:00.000 NULL            18:08:43.000
```

I've done row to column query before but the data can SUM, so it was easy to make it as a column but this one contains the date and time on the same field.

Any will be appreciated, TIA.

Comment: can you show your query?

Comment: Can you describe with words (in addition to providing the example) what you are trying to achieve. What if there are multiple As and Bs that do not match?

Comment: @ntalbs, the query is quite simple and i didnt use any sub queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT DATE_Field, 
MAX(CASE STATUS WHEN 'A' THEN Date_Time END) A,
MAX(CASE STATUS WHEN 'B' THEN Date_Time END) B
FROM 
(
SELECT CONVERT(Date,DateField,101) Date_Field, 
CONVERT(Time,DateField) Date_Time, Status
FROM YourTable
) v
GROUP BY DATE_Field
```

Comment: it needs to be a varchar(10) because it uses a 4 digit year with 2 /s.

Comment: Thanks rs, that solves the grouping problem i have, thanks to darin for the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can give this a try, you may need a substring rather than convert time.  Not quote sure if that conversion works correctly...

```
select convert(varchar(10),isnull(a.Date,b.Date),101),
   convert(time,a.Date) A,
   convert(time,b.Date) B
from table a
inner join table b 
on convert(varchar(10),a.Date,101) = convert(varchar(10),b.Date,101)
where a.Status = 'A'
and b.Status = 'B'
```